# Can I use xor on numpy matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 2 numpy matrix like this.

**matrix1**

```
arr1 =
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

**matrix2**

```
arr2 =
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I want to find similarity of these matrices. I think `xor` can be used on matrices. Xor operation should show where values are different and then I can count value 1 to calculate a percentage of similarity. I don't know how to use `xor` in python.

This code doesn't work: `a = arr1 xor arr2` .

Comment: Are all elements `0` or `1`?

Comment: XOR in Python is `^`, not `xor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `arr1 != arr2` which results in:

```
>>> arr1 != arr2
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and then use `.sum()` since `int(False)` is `0` and `int(True)` is `1`:

```
>>> (arr1 != arr2).sum()
2
```

So there are two indices for which `arr1[i,j]` is not equal to `arr2[i,j]`.

If you want to calculate the similarity (here defined as the number of elements that are the same) you can use:

```
>>> (arr1 == arr2).sum()/arr1.size
0.77777777777777779
```

so 77.77% of the elements are the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the inbuilt function [bitwise_xor](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html)

Answer (score 1):

A XOR B means:

(A and not B) or (B and not A):

```
AxorB = (A>B)+(B>A)
```

... at least for Boolean arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you have binary ndarrays then you could use `logical_xor()` too:

```
np.logical_xor(arr1, arr2).sum()
# 2
```